# Stackblitz VS Visual Studio?

Tags: angular

I am stuck since yesterday, when I use Stackblitz the graphic works correctly, however when I copy the code on Angular 12, I have several
errors. I don't understand why ?

The code on Stackblitz is [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-nrdwf6?file=src/index.html) (it works)

I have 2 error messages on Visual Studio.

[My errors in image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZluAL.png)

or below:

```
Error: src/app/line-chart/line-chart.component.html:3:64 - error TS2322: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'ChartType'.

3 [options]="lineChartOptions" [legend]="lineChartLegend" [chartType]="lineChartType" [plugins]="lineChartPlugins">
```

```
src/app/line-chart/line-chart.component.ts:7:16
7   templateUrl: './line-chart.component.html',
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Error occurs in the template of component LineChartComponent.
```

I copied each step below:

```
ng new graphic 
ng g component line-chart
npm i chart.js@2.8.0
npm i ng2-charts@2.2.0
```

**line-chart.component.html**

```
<div style="display: block;">
  <canvas baseChart width="500" height="200" [datasets]="lineChartData" [labels]="lineChartLabels"
    [options]="lineChartOptions" [legend]="lineChartLegend" [chartType]="lineChartType" [plugins]="lineChartPlugins">
  </canvas>
</div>
```

**line-chart.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ChartDataSets, ChartOptions } from 'chart.js';
import { Color, Label } from 'ng2-charts';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-line-chart',
  templateUrl: './line-chart.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./line-chart.component.css']
})
export class LineChartComponent implements OnInit {
  public lineChartData: ChartDataSets[] = [
    { data: [61, 59, 80, 65, 45, 55, 40, 56, 76, 65, 77, 60], label: 'Apple' },
    { data: [57, 50, 75, 87, 43, 46, 37, 48, 67, 56, 70, 50], label: 'Mi' }
  ];

  public lineChartLabels: Label[] = [
    'January',
    'February',
    'March',
    'April',
    'May',
    'June',
    'July',
    'August',
    'September',
    'October',
    'November',
    'December'
  ];

  public lineChartOptions = {
    responsive: true
  };

  public lineChartLegend = true;
  public lineChartType = 'line';
  public lineChartPlugins = [];

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<app-line-chart>

</app-line-chart>
```

**app-component.ts**

```
import { Component, VERSION } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular ' + VERSION.major;
}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ChartsModule } from 'ng2-charts';
import { LineChartComponent } from './line-chart/line-chart.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule, ChartsModule],
  declarations: [AppComponent, LineChartComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**hello.component.ts**

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  template: `<h1>Hello {{name}}!</h1>`,
  styles: [`h1 { font-family: Lato; }`]
})
export class HelloComponent  {
  @Input()
    name!: string; 
}
```

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Graphic</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <my-app></my-app>
</body>
</html>
```

If you have an idea, I am interested because I want to understand the problem.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/template-typecheck

Comment: @eko: I have to change in the file `app.component.ts` this lines?          
                                                                                                                                                                                   `@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})`

Comment: No, it's a tsconfig.json field. You should read the whole document. But to give you a quick answer, I wouldn't recommend disabling it. Typechecking is there for a good reason. You should just typecast the `ChartType`. Here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-8frfuy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fline-chart%2Fline-chart.component.ts. Notice I imported the `ChartType` and assigned the type of `lineChartType` to that on line 36

Comment: [Same post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68695796/why-my-graphic-doesnt-display-the-page-is-white), new [account](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16356732/christine)? 4th time is a charm, I guess.

Comment: @eko: Thank you eko the problem is resolved. Thank you a lot :-)

Answer (score 0):

What worked is to download the project from Stackblitz.

Replace the content of the `package.json` file with this:

```
{
  "name": "angular",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^12.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "^12.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^12.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "^12.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^12.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^12.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^12.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "^12.1.0",
    "chart.js": "2.8.0",
    "ng2-charts": "2.2.0",
    "rxjs": "^7.1.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.11.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~12.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~4.3.5"
  }
}
```

To be on safe side after making this change delete `node_modules` folder.

Then issue a commad `npm i` to install all required dependencies

And finally `npm start` it should compile without any issue.

Comment: I tried but I always have the same problem. The solution is to add ` public lineChartType: ChartType = 'line';` on line.chart.component.ts. It works ! :-)

Answer (score 0):

When using Angular12, its better to leave the strict check **ON**. It helps in a lot of ways.

The issue is because the variable you provide for the attribute should be of *ChartType*. The *ChartType* type would be imported in the component for sure. You can go to the definition of that type and get an idea of what the type would look like.

Then just give the type of provided variable as ChartType

Comment: Yes, I modified ! ^^